# Multiline comments in code blocks don't appear in README.md

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am currently documenting how to document code on one of my projects, and to do so I am writing a README.md document that I am putting as frontpage of the documentation that I generate using Doxygen 1.8.13.

I tried to put some examples inside the README as code blocks, but the comments used by Doxygen are multiline comments and the code blocks seem to skip the multiline comments when generating the Markdown page.

Here is an example of what happens.

This is what I would like to have:

```c
/** @def MACRO
 *  @brief Short description of the macro MACRO
 */
#define MACRO 0
```

This is what I have to write for the code block to appear (there seems to be issues with the "@" symbol):

```c
/** \@def MACRO
 *  \@brief Short description of the macro MACRO
 */
#define MACRO 0
```

This is the result I get when I generate the documentation with the code block right above:

```c
#define MACRO 0
```

I know that the multiline comments would appear in the code blocks without specifying the language of the code block (writing three backticks "`" instead of three backticks and c), but I would like to keep highlighting the syntax of the C code.

Do you know how to solve the problem with the "@", and most importantly do you know if there is a way for the multiline comments to appear in the code blocks whilst keeping the highlighting of C code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is quite old (December 29, 2016) the current doxygen version is 1.9.3 so please update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have the following source file `Readme.md`:

````
The required docu:

```
/** @def MACRO
 *  @brief Short description of the macro MACRO
 */
#define MACRO 0
```
````

and doxygen settings (`Doxyfile`):

```
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE=Readme.md
```

I get with the 1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473) version, I get:

[image]

So from the question I think this is required (when not add exact code (as text) and the resulting output in the original question).

In case one wants to render it like `C` code one should use for the opening backticks: ```` ```c ```` and one should also set `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS=NO` otherwise the comment will not be shown.
When doing this I get:

[image]

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you for answering my question. I have now updated Doxygen to version 1.9.2, but the problem is still there. Let me explain: using 3 backticks ``` works as the comments appear in the code block, but I would like to use ```c to create my code blocks and have the highlighting of C code just like on a C development software. Do you think it would be possible? Thank you!

Comment: 1.9.2 is already a better version, pity that you didn't go directly to 1.9.3. With the 1.9.2 version I see the same output as with the 1.9.3 version. When using the `C` code highlighting you should have a look at the setting of `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS`, in your case this should probably be `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS=NO`. It looks to me that `#define ...`  is colored like a preprocessing command and the comment block is colored like comment.

Comment: I changed the STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS to NO and now it works. Thank you very much for your help!